# Git is consistently deleting 2 directories from my repository, how can I troubleshoot this?

Tags: git, version-control

I don't expect someone to solve my problem, but I am not quite sure how to troubleshoot this.  If I do a "git status", I get:

```
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       deleted:    app/controllers/application.rb
#
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#
#       modified:   app/views/main/index.html.erb
#       modified:   public/stylesheets/bandop.css
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       vendor/plugins/contacts/.gitignore
#       vendor/plugins/contacts/.gitmodules
```

but if I do "git add ." and then "git status", I get:

```
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       deleted:    app/controllers/application.rb
#       modified:   app/views/main/index.html.erb
#       modified:   public/stylesheets/bandop.css
#       new file:   vendor/plugins/blackbook
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/CHANGES.markdown
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/Manifest.txt
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/README.markdown
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/Rakefile
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/blackbook.gemspec
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/debug_blackbook.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/init.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/lib/blackbook.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/lib/blackbook/exporter/base.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/lib/blackbook/exporter/vcf.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/lib/blackbook/exporter/xml.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/lib/blackbook/importer/aol.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/lib/blackbook/importer/base.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/lib/blackbook/importer/csv.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/lib/blackbook/importer/freenet.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/lib/blackbook/importer/gmail.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/lib/blackbook/importer/gmx.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/lib/blackbook/importer/hotmail.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/lib/blackbook/importer/page_scraper.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/lib/blackbook/importer/web.de.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/lib/blackbook/importer/yahoo.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/fixtures/aol_new_contacts.html
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/fixtures/gmail.csv
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/fixtures/gmail_bad_login_response_stage_2.html
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/fixtures/gmail_contacts.html
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/fixtures/gmail_login_response_stage_1.html
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/fixtures/gmail_login_response_stage_2.html
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/fixtures/gmail_login_response_stage_2a.html
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/fixtures/gmail_login_response_stage_3.html
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/fixtures/gmail_redirect_body.html
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/fixtures/hotmail_bad_login_response_stage_2.html
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/fixtures/hotmail_contacts.html
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/fixtures/hotmail_login_response_stage_1.html
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/fixtures/hotmail_login_response_stage_2.html
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/fixtures/hotmail_login_response_stage_3.html
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/fixtures/hotmail_scrape_first_page.html
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/fixtures/hotmail_scrape_response_stage_1.html
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/fixtures/hotmail_scrape_response_stage_2.html
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/fixtures/hotmail_scrape_response_stage_3.html
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/fixtures/yahoo_bad_login_response_stage_2.html
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/fixtures/yahoo_contacts.csv
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/fixtures/yahoo_contacts_not_logged_in.html
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/fixtures/yahoo_contacts_stage_1.html
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/fixtures/yahoo_login_response_stage_1.html
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/fixtures/yahoo_login_response_stage_2.html
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/fixtures/yahoo_no_user_response_stage_2.html
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/freenet_importer_test.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/gmx_importer_test.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/scripts/live_test.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/test_blackbook.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/test_blackbook_exporter_base.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/test_blackbook_exporter_vcf.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/test_blackbook_exporter_xml.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/test_blackbook_importer_aol.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/test_blackbook_importer_base.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/test_blackbook_importer_csv.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/test_blackbook_importer_gmail.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/test_blackbook_importer_hotmail.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/test_blackbook_importer_page_scraper.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/test_blackbook_importer_yahoo.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/test_helper.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/test/web.de_importer_test.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/vendor/plugins/blackbook/lib/autotest/blackbook.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/blackbook/vendor/plugins/blackbook/lib/autotest/discover.rb
#       new file:   vendor/plugins/contacts
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/MIT-LICENSE
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/README.rdoc
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/Rakefile
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/lib/config/contacts.yml
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/lib/contacts.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/lib/contacts/flickr.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/lib/contacts/google.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/lib/contacts/version.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/lib/contacts/windows_live.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/lib/contacts/yahoo.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/spec/contact_spec.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/spec/feeds/contacts.yml
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/spec/feeds/flickr/auth.getFrob.xml
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/spec/feeds/flickr/auth.getToken.xml
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/spec/feeds/google-many.xml
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/spec/feeds/google-single.xml
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/spec/feeds/wl_contacts.xml
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/spec/feeds/yh_contacts.txt
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/spec/feeds/yh_credential.xml
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/spec/flickr/auth_spec.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/spec/gmail/auth_spec.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/spec/gmail/fetching_spec.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/spec/rcov.opts
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/spec/spec.opts
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/spec/spec_helper.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/spec/windows_live/windows_live_spec.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/spec/yahoo/yahoo_spec.rb
#       deleted:    vendor/plugins/contacts/vendor/windowslivelogin.rb
```

The problem is I never deleted any of those files, git just thinks I did.  My workaround is to do "git add vendor/plugins/contacts/*" and "git add vendor/plugins/blackbook/*" every time before I commit but this is terrible.  Can anyone provide direction on this?

## UPDATE:

Thanks to the comments, I have figured out most of the problem.  I never treated my plugins as submodules even though they were source controlled.

So far, I have deleted SCM from the blackbook plugin (I don't actually need or want it). And I removed the contacts entirely and did:

```
git submodule add repo_address local_address
git submodule init
git submodule update
git add vendor/plugins/contacts
git add .
git commit -m "submodule should be committing now"
```

but now the problem is that while the contacts plugin code exists in my local repo.  i can't get it to commit to my remote repo.  even after "git add ." or more explicitly "git add vendor/plugins/contacts" ....any ideas here?

Thank you!

Comment: added some suggestions centered around the submodules topic

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Weird. You have a [blog entry](http://marcostoledo.com/git-add-mistakenly-deletes-a-directory-which-wasnt-touched-bug/) reporting that exact same issue. With submodules, as mentioned in [Dave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952825/git-is-consistently-deleting-2-directories-from-my-repository-how-can-i-troubles/952898#952898).

> This was only fixed by removing the version control on the “restful_authentication” directory:

```
.~/projects/bushi2do master $ rm -rf vendor/plugins/restful_authentication/.git
.~/projects/bushi2do master $ git add .
.~/projects/bushi2do master $ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

> The downside to this fix is that you can no longer ‘git pull’ on the plugin’s directory to grab the updates.

---

How about

```
git rm --cached vendor/plugins/contacts
git rm --cached vendor/plugins/blackbook
```

?

And how did you declare your submodules within you plugins directory ?

Because I remember a classic catch with submodules.
If you use git submodules, don't do `git add foo/` (watch that trailing slash!) if foo is your submodule. It gets messy.

From [here](http://august.lilleaas.net/git_submodules):

**When you use git add on a submodule, make sure you don’t have a tailing slash.**

```
> git add local/path
  -- adds the submodule

> git add local/path/
  -- adds all the files in the submodule directly into your repository, big no-no
```

Comment: you are right about the problem and thanks for the code to remove scm from a module

Comment: git rm --cached vendor/plugins/contacts will remove the plugin which i don't want to do.  i didn't even bother with submodules because i didn't know i had to.  i just did a git clone in my vendors/plugins directory.  so im learning this the hard way. the main issue i see now is a bunch of "No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path ..."  git probably sees that i have git repos underneath but not defined as submodules (therefore it has no repo to update). ....still working on it.

Answer (score 1):

Can't tell you for sure, but I'd look into whether the problem is related to having the "blackbook" and "contacts" plugins specified as git submodules.

Comment: this is definitely the problem, looking into a solution