# initialize submodule using git

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I added this to my application:

```
https://github.com/fpotter/juggernaut-cocoa
```

In the instructions, it says:

```
If you have git 1.7+ git clone git://github.com/fpotter/juggernaut-cocoa.git --recursive
```

It doesnt say where to clone it, so I clone it in my Documents folder. Then I copy the AsyncSocket.h, AsyncSocket.m, WebSocket.h, WebSocket.m, SocketIoClient.h, SocketIoClient.m, JuggernautClient.h, JuggernautClient.m files to my project in a folder I created called juggernaut-cocoa inside vendor.

However, while the files work on my local machine, when i push to github they are never added. All I see is a little green folder:

http://i47.tinypic.com/2ajnkzl.jpg

But when I try to clone my repository from another computer, the files are not there, they were never added to git.

I then tried to clone their project into my Vendor folder, and then ran git submodule init but got this:

```
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'Vendor/juggernaut-cocoa'
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `AsyncSocket.m`, `WebSocket.h`, ... are all files of [github.com/erichocean/cocoa-websocket](https://github.com/erichocean/cocoa-websocket/tree/master/AsyncSocket), which is:

- a submodule of [github.com/fpotter/socketio-cocoa](https://github.com/fpotter/socketio-cocoa),
- which *itself* is a submodule of [github.com/fpotter/juggernaut-cocoa](https://github.com/fpotter/juggernaut-cocoa) (hence the little green folder on Github)

So if you modify anything in a sub-submodule, you would have to:

- push those modif to `erichocean/cocoa-websocket`, but also
- committing that repo id back in `fpotter/socketio-cocoa` (the parent repo of `cocoa-websocket`), and push that, and then
- committing the new `fpotter/socketio-cocoa` repo id back in `fpotter/juggernaut-cocoa` (its parent repo), and push that...

So be sure that is what you actually want to do/ can do (since you need to have write access to those repo, ie be declared as a collaborator).

Regarding your error message, check [No submodule mapping found in .gitmodule for a path that's not a submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11474212/6309).

Comment: I dont want to modify anything. I just want to add those files in my repository

Answer (score 0):

If you manually copy files from another project into yours, they don't become part of your repo, unless you add them:

```
git add vendor/juggernaut-cocoa/
git commit
```

If you want to use a submodule instead, adding it is not done by manual cloning and then calling "git submodule init".
Instead you simply call `git submodule add`.

First, `cd` to the root of your main project. Then

```
git submodule add https://github.com/fpotter/juggernaut-cocoa vendor/juggernaut-cocoa
git commit
```