# No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

When I run

```
git submodule update
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'Classes/lib/AFKissXMLRequestOperation'
```

But I have no submodule `Classes/lib/AFKissXMLRequestOperation` in current repos

My git config is:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = false
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@github.com:why_ios.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[submodule "External/ios-SDNestedTable"]
    url = git@github.com:why/ios-SDNestedTable.git
[submodule "External/PSStackedView"]
    url = git@github.com:why/PSStackedView.git
```

and .gitmodules is:

```
[submodule "External/ios-SDNestedTable"]
    path = External/ios-SDNestedTable
    url = git@github.com:why/ios-SDNestedTable.git
[submodule "External/PSStackedView"]
    path = External/PSStackedView
    url = git@github.com:why/PSStackedView.git
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185365/no-submodule-mapping-found-in-gitmodule-for-a-path-thats-not-a-submodule

Answer (score 103, accepted):

check that you have the proper setting in `.git/modules` as well. Since a few versions ago, git adds an entry there.

Also, the tree probably has a commit object at that path. To get rid of it you can

```
git rm --cached Classes/lib/AFKissXMLRequestOperation
```

that should get rid of it once and for all.

Comment: you sir, saved me from certain insanity!

Comment: I did a git rm --cached myFile but now I am unabled to do a git init on the server where it was done. I have a cluster of 4 machines and only this one is doing nothing. How to rebuild this cache?

Comment: ok this was a stupid question, git reset HEAD myFile and I am good again, sorry for disturb !

Comment: UPvote this if you are from the future where the authors of git finally implement `git submodule update --init --recursive --justworkdammit`

Comment: For some reason, mine required single quotes around the path and would not work with out it. `git rm --cached 'Classes/lib/AFKissXMLRequestOperation'`

Comment: The final "Also" step worked when I had neither `.gitmodules` nor `.git/modules` - thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Just leaving this here for anyone using `git` on Windows. It is possible to follow all of the answers online and still have it not work due to `git`'s handling of path separators.
E.g.:

My problem case was adding `hugo` themes via `submodule`:

`git submodule add https://github.com/danielkvist/hugo-terrassa-theme.git themes\terrassa`

will result in a `.gitmodules` like:

```
[submodule "themes\\terrassa"]
    path = themes\\terrassa
    url = https://github.com/danielkvist/hugo-terrassa-theme.git
```

Which will cause problems for `git submodule [status || init || ...]`

Manually replacing the separators to:

```
[submodule "themes/terrassa"]
    path = themes/terrassa
    url = https://github.com/danielkvist/hugo-terrassa-theme.git
```

...solved it for me.

Also solved the deployment on Netlify since they use *nix server images.