# After putting some git repositories into another, git does not track changes any more

Tags: git, debugging, composer-php

I have a git repository (`test-dev`) and several dependent git repositories (they are originally managed using composer). Lets call them `module-1`, `module-2`

I copied the main git repository to a new location / name (`test-deploy`) and now want to include those other repositories directly into the new repository.

So I copied the contents of those module repositories into the new `test-deploy` one.

Now I had some .git files in those subdirectories which I removed. Also the .gitignore files of the sub repositories.

Now I can not add those files anymore to the parent-git.

How can I trace this problem?

*EDIT (Clarification):*

I only want one single `.git` - I also do not want to have any gitmodules or something like that.

The final repository should be completely self-contained.

*EDIT*

From the root of `test-deploy`:

```
$ git status
 ...
    nothing to commit (working directory clean)
$ git submodule
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'vendor/foo/foo_bar'
```

Comment: Don't do that.  You need a `.git` folder for each repo.

Comment: Additionally, you'll want to ensure that you've maintained your `.gitmodules` during your copy/pasting of repos.

Comment: @SLaks I clarified my question - I want to rip out this .git - the submodules shall not have any .git intelligence any more in this case.

Comment: @cjc343 see edit --- I did actually not use gitmodules, but composer might have created one

Comment: @Alex: Then you don't want to use submodules at all.

Comment: Don't call them submodules if they're not submodules. If you've already checked them in as submodules, you'll probably need to untrack them before you can track them as folders.

Comment: @cjc343 Good point - edited again.

Comment: Could you add outputs for `git status` and `git submodule`?

Comment: @cjc343: Edit .. Actually I am redoing it all again now (but do not delete this damaged repo yet) - still it could be interesting to dig why that happened.

Comment: If you're still interested in pursuing the original issue at all, is there any difference if you run both of those from the root of your repo instead?

Comment: @cjc343: I always like to learn. The above git status / submodules output is from the root of `test-deploy`

Comment: I didn't really understand what you did (a short example to reproduce it would be nice, I'm a little bit familiar with magento-composer-installer), but: the normal way of handling that error didn't help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720034/no-submodule-mapping-found-in-gitmodules-for-path

Comment: Odd -- what led to my question is the `No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'vendor/foo/foo_bar'` line, which I thought might be saying you're in the `vendor/foo/foo_bar` directory. It seems there was some partial submodule setup that was causing that message.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround (basically I re-did it)

The real cause of the problem is still unclear.

- First of all do the composer installation (I am using magento-composer-installer) using the deploy strategy copy - otherwise it would create lots of symlinks.
- Now copy everything
- But remove the `.git`
- Do a new `git init`
- Also remove the vendor/ folder - I do not need it in this specific case of mine not any more
- git add / git commit