# No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path and missing .gitmodules file

Tags: git, git-submodules

When I run `git submodule init`, I get the following error:

> No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'xxx'

I searched for a `.gitmodules` file and I cannot find it anywhere.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185365/no-submodule-mapping-found-in-gitmodule-for-a-path-thats-not-a-submodule) most popular SO question on the same topic. 
But unfortunately, I cannot solve the problem. Especially given that I no longer have `.gitmodules`.

According to my GitHub private repo, I still have submodules for my repository. Just that I cannot find the `.gitmodules` file anywhere.

Comment: I think it might be worth noting that you can create a submodule accidentally if you git init a new repo inside of an existing repo (the definition of a "submodule"). If you do this, the .gitmodule file won't be created.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

1. Make sure that there are no `submodule` sections in `.git/config`. If there are, remove them.
2. Do `git rm --cached <path_to_submodule>`.

Comment: Just step 2 above was enough for me; git rm --cached <path_to_submodule> .

Comment: and just don't forget to `git commit` after the second step

Comment: Calling `git rm --cached` gives `fatal: Please, stage your changes to .gitmodules or stash them to proceed`.

Comment: @QuolonelQuestions I got that too .. `git add .gitmodules` will stage the file, then the `git rm --cached <submodule_path>` worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I was in the middle of a rebase and was still able to use this answer.

Answer (score 5):

just got over the same issue yesterday, after having deleted by hand **the entry in .gitmodules** (e.g. nano .gitmodules), I had to go with

```
git rm --cached <pathtomodule>
```

which returned a message

```
rm '<pathtomodule>'
```

then I needed a

```
git commit -m "delete cached modules"
```

and validated the submodule deletion.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the above I also had to remove `.gitmodules`.

Comment: In my case I didn't delete the entire file, but removed the now invalid entries and things started working again. Thanks!