# No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'sinatra-bootstrap'

Tags: ruby, git, twitter-bootstrap, amazon-web-services, sinatra

When I try to deploy to AWS in the log I receive the following error:

```
[Wed, 13 Nov 2013 15:32:35 +0000] ERROR: deploy[/srv/www/rn] (/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20131106095250_142/cookbooks/deploy/definitions/opsworks_deploy.rb:63:in `from_file') had an error:

git submodule init && git submodule update returned 1, expected 0

---- Begin output of git submodule init && git submodule update ----

STDOUT: STDERR: No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'sinatra-bootstrap'

---- End output of git submodule init && git submodule update ----
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that the [index special entry representing the submodule SHA1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309) for `sinatra-bootstrap` could have been replaced with a plain old folder instead.

Try to remove it from the index:

```
git rm --cached `sinatra-bootstrap` 
git submodule update --init
```

If have no entry in your .gitmodules and want one for a `sinatra-bootstrap` path, then you will need to properly add it first

```
git submodule add /url/for/sinatra-bootstrap sinatra-bootstrap
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because in your local repo there is a folder that has an .git dir, a so called submodule(a repo inside your repo)

try this: [No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path and missing .gitmodules file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017335/no-submodule-mapping-found-in-gitmodules-for-path-and-missing-gitmodules-file)