# Git: How to clean information about submodules?

Tags: git-submodules

I'm attempting to add several files to a git project, but getting some cryptic submodule errors.

`git submodule`

results in the following error:

`No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path '.vim/bundle/ctrlsf.vim'`

Where are these mappings coming from, and how can I remove them?

Originally, I of course cloned these projects from git... However, I have no need for their submodule metadata any longer.

Answer (score 0):

They are in the .gitmodules file, in the same dir as your .git file.
See [How do I remove a submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule)

Comment: Thanks for this response, however, there is no .gitmodules file... that's the crux of the question..  Why is git complaining when there isn't a .gitmodules setup to begin with?  I assume maybe when you have nested directories and so on there might be a case where a gitmodule gets recursively propogated up somehow

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185365/no-submodule-mapping-found-in-gitmodule-for-a-path-thats-not-a-submodule