# No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules - how to solve the general case?

Tags: git

Following up to this question: [No submodule mapping found in .gitmodule for a path that's not a submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185365/no-submodule-mapping-found-in-gitmodule-for-a-path-thats-not-a-submodule)

If you remove a submodule from `.gitmodules`, and then run `git submodule update --init`, git may complain

```
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'my/submodule
```

The generally accepted solution is to run

```
git rm --cached my/submodule
```

and afterwards run `git submodule update --init` again.

**What's a good way to deal with this in Continuous Integration?**

I can't SSH into the CI server every time somebody remotes a submodule, and neither do I want to wipe the entire git repository.

Is there a git command with which I can `git rm` all such former submodules, where I don't have to give the explicit path (e.g. `my/submodule`), so that I can run every time CI runs, and have `git submodule update --init` work every time?

Comment: What are your thoughts on making a bash script to do all that for you? it would ssh into the box and rm cached and save you a few commands each time.

Comment: @Ajk_P I would like the CI to work in a fully automated fashion, without human interaction. It seems weird to me that git would leave me in a state that needs to be handled by a human, as its automation abilities are usually quite good.