# No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'LibTecho'

Tags: git, git-submodules

There are 3 submodules in my directory.

I am trying to update all my submodules using the command

```
   git submodule foreach git submodule update
```

Two of them are updated fine and One is throwing the error:

```
 No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'LibTecho'
```

I am unable to do init and update for the module '`LibTecho`'

Here is my **.gitmodules**

```
[submodule "TechEngine"]
    path = TechEngine
    url = git@github.com:TechApp/TechEngine.git
[submodule "LibTechCreate"]
    path = LibSTechCreate
    url = git@github.com:TechApp/LibTechCreate.git
[submodule "LibTecho"]
    path = LibTecho
    url = git@github.com:TechApp/LibTecho.git
```

I tried:

1. Removing the submodule and adding it again as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185365/no-submodule-mapping-found-in-gitmodule-for-a-path-thats-not-a-submodule)

   ```
   git rm --cached LibTecho
   ```

and

```
   git submodule add git@github.com:TechApp/LibTecho.git
```

2. Checked the entries which reference to submodule:

   ```
   git ls-files --stage | grep 160000
   ```

and I found that all three libs are listed properly.

3. I removed the submodule and then cloned again:

   ```
   git clone --recursive git@github.com:TechApp/LibTecho.git
   ```
4. Removed the submodules section in .git/config file

   - There are no other .gitmodules file in my directory.

Even after multiple tries, I'm unable to update my submodule.

Edit:

when I try to pull from submodule git using source tree, I get this error message too:

> git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c
>   credential.helper=sourcetree submodule update --init --recursive  No
>   submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'LibTecho'

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I did wrong.

I am doing the

```
  git rm --cached LibTecho
```

in the project directory folder.

To resolve this issue, I have to move to the submodule folder ,in my case it is LibTecho, and then do

```
 git rm --cached LibTecho
```

and do `git submodule update --init`