# Removing root directory from Git

Tags: git, bitbucket

This question is NOT duplicate , so plz dont flag is duplicate, as my scenario is different

I have my git repo in folder /data/wwwdata, wwwdata is the root of git, it has the repository in it. when i try to to get git status, i get

> modified:   wwwdata (modified content)

as it is the root folder of my git repo, if i run command git rm -r --cached wwwdata , will it remove everything from git repository as well? (recursively all files in it) but will not remove local data?
how can i only remove this folder from git repo?

i am also getting error

```
"Please check : No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'wwwdata'"
```

is it due to above problem?

Comment: It seems paradoxical to me that `wwwdata` contains the repo, and that `git status` mentions that this directory is modified. Where is the `.git` directory? And in which directory are you when you run `git status`?

Comment: You have `wwwdata` partly, but not completely, set up as a submodule.  Until you put it into a consistent state—not a submodule at all, or a correctly submodule-ized submodule—you will not be able to do anything useful with it.

Comment: @gturri: git directory is under "/data/wwwdata/.git" i am running git status under /data/wwwdata/

Comment: @torek: its solution? any workaround to fix it?

Comment: I avoid submodules myself.  However, searching for the string "No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules" in google, the top three hits are all stackoverflow questions.  Probable duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4185365/1256452