# No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'paquete/static/lib/cgxp'

Tags: build, mapping, git-submodules

I am installing geomapfish.

I am in this step.

```
https://camptocamp.github.io/c2cgeoportal/master/integrator/install_application.html#apache-wsgi-conf-mako

Then you can build and install the application with the command:

$ make -f <user>.mk build
```

But in my case I have this erro:

```
git submodule update --init
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'paquete/static/lib/cgxp'
CONST_Makefile:1030: recipe for target '.git/modules/proyecto1/static/lib/cgxp/HEAD' failed
make: *** [.git/modules/proyecto1/static/lib/cgxp/HEAD] Error 1
```

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185365/no-submodule-mapping-found-in-gitmodule-for-a-path-thats-not-a-submodule)

And try to follow it but I don't know what is the problem.

If I type:

```
...# git ls-files --stage | grep 160000
```

This is the commandline says:

```
160000 e1097abee85078e0de1f8e0a4d5269e6a7a9f72f 0   cgxp
160000 7437277b10fbf23206ed75fd6d0924b61d6153be 0   cgxp2
160000 7437277b10fbf23206ed75fd6d0924b61d6153be 0   paquete/static/lib/cgxp
```

I think I only need one of them.

Could any help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My old answer was about removing that entry from the index, since the .gitmodules did not reference it.

```
git rm --cached paquete/static/lib/cgxp
```

But check the content of the `.gitmodules` to see if there should be a "cgxp" repo.

If you find its url, you can add it back with:

```
git submodule add -- /url/of/cgxp paquete/static/lib/cgxp
```

Comment: @Iván what do you get? What "doesn't work" means? What your .gitmodules include.

Comment: I type git rm paquete/static/lib/cgxp and it says:                                   
     error: the following submodule (or one of its nested submodules)
uses a .git directory:
    paquete/static/lib/cgxp
(use 'rm -rf' if you really want to remove it including all of its history)

Comment: @Iván git rm --cached then

Comment: I try with git rm -rf but its answer is the same

Comment: @Iván By the way, consider (for this question or your other question) to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote and https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer: that is how this QA site works.