# Why are the steps I took to fix 'builds' in Netlify/Hugo not working?

Tags: hugo, netlify

Netlify/Hugo is not updating the changes I have pushed to Github. This is a weird issue since I have, as far as I am concerned, not done anything different from what I have been doing before this problem occurred.

I have followed the instructions of this [book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/netlify.html) and the one offered by of [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/docs/continuous-deployment/) but none worked.

I have also contacted Netlify but could not completely understand what I am supposed to do after they answered me. See below.

*When I take a look at your builds, I see hugo errors.  I suspect you'd get them locally too in case you use hugo 0.53 locally?  When you clone a FRESH COPY of your directory (rather than one you've made local changes in), and try to run hugo 0.53/extended, do builds work better?  If so then your next debugging steps will be here:  https://github.com/netlify/build-image#running-locally to run our build container yourself to try to debug.*

What I did based on this response was the following:

i) I went to RStudio and opened 'shell'  in 'Git'. There I wrote 'git clone https://github.com/website_address.git'.

ii) As a result of this command in Git, a new folder opened in the repository.

iii) Then I started 'command prompt' in my laptop to run hugo '0.53/extended'. 'C:\Users\NewUser>docker pull netlify/build:v0.53/extended'. This resulted in the following error message: 'docker' is not recognized as a internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I have made slight modifications to 'v.0.53/extended' but the error persists. I have also tried this line of code in Git but to no avail.

iv) I have also created a README folder in my Github repository and copied this snippet provided by Netlify:

`[![Netlify Status](https://api.netlify.com/api/v1/badges/b3749a18-96fa-4abc-bfc7-1d4a331ae78e/deploy-status)](https://app.netlify.com/sites/website_address/deploys)`

but the problem persists.

This is one of the error messages that Netlify shows:

`2:31:20 PM: Build ready to start
2:31:21 PM: build-image version: 9e0f207a27642d0115b1ca97cd5e8cebbe492f63
2:31:21 PM: build-image tag: v3.3.2
2:31:21 PM: buildbot version: 75cd99f62ada9e21edea53208e8baf0eab85a045
2:31:22 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
2:31:22 PM: Starting to download cache of 104.5MB
2:31:22 PM: Finished downloading cache in 626.785348ms
2:31:22 PM: Starting to extract cache
2:31:25 PM: Finished extracting cache in 3.003714699s
2:31:25 PM: Finished fetching cache in 3.716551911s
2:31:25 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
2:31:26 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
2:31:28 PM: Error checking out submodules: fatal: No url found for submodule path 'Blogdown' in .gitmodules
2:31:28 PM: Failing build: Failed to prepare repo
2:31:28 PM: failed during stage 'preparing repo': Error checking out submodules: fatal: No url found for submodule path 'Blogdown' in .gitmodules
: exit status 128
2:31:28 PM: Finished processing build request in 6.17222572s
2:31:28 PM: Shutting down logging, 0 messages pending`

I suspect that the answer for solving my problem is hinted here:

`Error checking out submodules: fatal: No url found for submodule path 'Blogdown' in .gitmodules`.

So I checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185365/no-submodule-mapping-found-in-gitmodule-for-a-path-thats-not-a-submodule/35207718) but I am still in the dark about what I am supposed to do.

I am obviously doing some(probably many)things wrong here. But I have no idea where and what these mistakes are.

It would be great if someone could guide a newbie like me out of this hole.

Much appreciated.

ps. Github and RStudio are communicating well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously, I've had similar issues in different projects. After trying a bit around I found a solution. My solution is to decouple the submodule and move the code into my codebase (or using a managed package for this).

To decouple the module go into your submodule folder, delete the .git folder and add the files to your git repository. On the command line I would do it like this:

```
// going into the submodule - might need to tweaked, depending on the exact path
cd Blogdown

// delete the git submodule
rm -rf .git

// going out of the directory
cd ..

// adding everything to git
git add .
```

With these steps (and potentially minor tweaks to the paths) I've been able to resolve this issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for the response @spekulatius. I believe the answer is correct but I could not really test it because I ended up deleting the repo (while trying to delete only the cloned one) and now have to start the blog all over again.

Comment: Ah, okay. That's cool. Maybe it helps someone else stumbling across the same issue.