# Where is the 'build command' in Netlify/Hugo?

Tags: hugo, netlify

I cannot fix the error message of 'failed' in Netlify when deploying from Github.

I have created a complete new blog and was deploying post by post since the previous attempts to deploy multiple files at once led to successive 'failed' messages.

I have contacted Netlify and they informed that I should add:

`;sleep 200; false`

at the end of my 'build command'.

The problem is where do I find this 'build command'?

I have looked everywhere at the **Site Settings** on Netlify but could not find where to add this code.

It would be great if someone could shed some light on my ignorance. (Not sure if this piece of information is relevant but I was using HUGO version 0.55.5)

Cheers,

ps. This issue is related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56158245/why-are-the-steps-i-took-to-fix-builds-in-netlify-hugo-not-working).

Answer (score 0):

I have still not figured out where to add

`;sleep 200; false`

as Netlify recommends.

However, I have solved my problem taking the following steps.

After you log into you Netfliy, click on the website you are having issues with.

At the top of the page click on **Deploys**. Under `Search Deploys` you will see a list of files starting with `Production:master@...`. Click on the last one that `failed`.

In the **Deploy log** you will see a line pointing you to a error such as:

`2:42:50 PM: ERROR 2019/05/16 21:42:50 "/opt/bui...`

Identify which file is causing the deploy to fail. Once it is identified, delete it from your files and then deploy again.

It should work. At least it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the Deploy Settings (Menu  -> Deploy -> Deploy Setting button):

https://app.netlify.com/sites/{xxx-siteid-xxx}/settings/deploys

In the Build Setting section, you can find build command, which by default is blank. You can give your custom build command there.