# git submodule update --init --force --remote

Tags: git, github, gitlab

When I pull submodule using `git submodule update --init --force --remote` it creates new files containing git diff for example

```
diff --git a/app/Services/Payment b/app/Services/Payment
index 72602bc..a726378 160000
--- a/app/Services/Payment
+++ b/app/Services/Payment
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit 72602bc5d9e7cef136043791242dfdcfd979370c
+Subproject commit a7263787e5515abe18e7cfe76af0f26d9f62ceb4
```

I don't what are these files and how to get rid of them and when I remove them the sobmodule checkout to the old commit

Comment: Technical note: you are not *pulling* a submodule. You are *cloning* a submodule or *checking out* a submodule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## TL;DR

Your issue here is the use of `--remote`.  Stop doing that.

## Long

You mention [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69781487/git-submodule-update-init-force-remote#comment123348533_69781906) on [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69781906/1256452) that:

> When I [run] `git status` [I get]
>
> ```
>     modified:   app/Services/Notification (new commits)
>     modified:   app/Services/Payment (new commits)
>     modified:   database/migrations (new commits)
> ```

The `(new commits)` part means: the commit hash ID your submodule is *actively using* (through its current checkout) differs from the commit hash ID your *index* (proposed next commit) says *should be used*.

There's a lot of jargon here ("submodules", "gitlinks", "index", "commit hash ID") and hence a lot to unpack.  We'll get to this in just a moment.

Note that the output of `git status` above is a more-compact representation of the output of `git diff` that you quoted in your original question:

> ```
> diff --git a/app/Services/Payment b/app/Services/Payment
> index 72602bc..a726378 160000
> --- a/app/Services/Payment
> +++ b/app/Services/Payment
> @@ -1 +1 @@
> -Subproject commit 72602bc5d9e7cef136043791242dfdcfd979370c
> +Subproject commit a7263787e5515abe18e7cfe76af0f26d9f62ceb4
> ```

What we see here is that for `app/Services/Payment`, your (main, top-level, "or superproject" repository's index says that this particular submodule *should* use commit `72602bc5d9e7cef136043791242dfdcfd979370c`.  But it's *actually* using commit `a7263787e5515abe18e7cfe76af0f26d9f62ceb4` instead.  We've just added one more jargon term to define: *superproject*.

#### Some initial definitions

Let's start with the definition of a *Git repository*.  A repository is, at its heart, a pair of databases.  One is a database of *commits* and other internal Git objects.  The other database holds names—human-readable names, because the names Git uses for its own objects are incomprehensible.

A *commit* is one of the four types of internal objects that Git stores in the first—usually much larger—database.  These commits are *numbered*, with very large numbers that range up to 2<sup>160</sup>-1.  These numbers are expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), as, e.g., `72602bc5d9e7cef136043791242dfdcfd979370c`.  (The commits are the only ones you normally interact with in the way we're about to describe, so we'll just conveniently ignore the remaining three, but they're also all numbered.)

The numbers *look* random, though they're actually the output of a cryptographic hashing function and hence entirely *non*-random.  The fact that they come out of a hash function is why we call them *hash IDs* too.  But the real point here is that they seem to be totally scrambled, and no *human* is ever going to remember them.  We need a computer for that.

Fortunately, we *have* a computer.  We simply have the computer remember these hash IDs for us, using things like branch names and tag names.  Each commit also stores, within itself, the hash ID(s) or some previous commits.  We don't really need to worry about that right here, but this is how branches *really* work in Git.

So:

- a *repository* is
- a pair of databases, where one database holds *commits*
- which have *hash IDs* or big ugly numbers.

We and Git use the second database, of names, to find the hash IDs of particular commits, and we use the commits to find more hash IDs of more commits, and so on.

#### Commits are read-only: the *working tree* and the *index*

Now, a crucial thing to know *about* these commits—and indeed all of Git's internal objects—is that they are all *read only*.  They have to be, because of the hashing trick: the hash ID is a function of *every single bit that goes into the internal object*, and we *find* the object by the hash ID, so the hash ID must always match.  If the hash ID of some object we *extract from* the database doesn't match the hash ID we used to *find it in* the database, Git decides the database is corrupt.<sup>1</sup>

So the commits are completely read-only.  Not only that, but the *files inside each commit*—we didn't define this earlier, but each commit holds a full snapshot of every file—are in a special Git-only format, compressed and de-duplicated, that only Git can read.  (Literally nothing can *write over them* since everything is read-only.)

What this means is that just to *use* some commit, we must *extract* that commit.  Git will extract a commit by:

- reading the compressed and Git-ified files that are inside the commit;
- expanding them into ordinary read/write files; and
- writing out those files into a *working tree*.

This *working tree*—another bit of jargon—is where we actually do our work.  Here, we can see, read, and even write to files.  They exist *as* files, not as read-only, Git-only database entries.  So, now we can get work done.

The working tree also enables us to make *new* commits, but here, Git inserts an extra stumbling block.  Before Git will *allow* us to make a new commit, Git requires that we *copy any updated files back into Git*.

This step actually makes a certain amount of sense, because the files we see and work on / with in our working tree are *not **in** Git at all*.  They may have been *copied out of* Git (out of a commit or one of its supporting objects) but once they are out, they are out.

Git calls the place that Git makes us re-copy updated files by three different names: the *index*, which as a name makes no sense by itself; the *staging area*, which refers to how we and Git *use* the index—and the *cache*, which is hardly ever used any more but still shows up as the flag in `git rm --cached` for instance.

The index's role *as staging area* is pretty straightforward.  It takes on an expanded role during merge conflicts, but since we are not worried about these here, we'll just look at how we and Git use it as a staging area.

When we first *check out* a commit—with `git checkout` or `git switch`—Git needs to expand out all the compressed and Git-ified files into our working tree.  But Git secretly sticks a "copy" of each of these files into its index / staging-area.  I put the word "copy" in quotes here because Git's internal file copies are all *de-duplicated*.  This is why a Git repository doesn't become enormously fat even though every commit stores every file: most commits *re-use* most files, and in this case, the re-used file takes no space at all, because it's been de-duplicated away.

The same goes for these index "copies": they're *duplicates*, because the file in question is *in the commit*.  So the index "copies" take no space.<sup>2</sup>  But the key for making a new *commit* is this: the index copies are exactly what is going to go into the *next commit*.

In other words, the index holds your *proposed next commit*.  Right now, having done a "clean" checkout of some existing commit, the index matches the commit.  But now you can modify some file(s) in the working tree, if you like.  Once you have modified a *working tree* file, you're *required to copy it back into Git's index*.  You do this with `git add`, which:

- reads the working tree copy;
- compresses it and otherwise Git-ifies it;
- checks to see if the result is a duplicate; and
- if it *is* a duplicate, uses the original (throwing away the temporary Git-ified copy), otherwise uses the new Git-ified file, and uses this to update the index.

The result is that the index now contains your proposed next commit—just as it did *before* you ran `git add`.  It's just that now, your proposed next commit *has been updated*.

You repeat this for all files you intend to update: update them in the working tree, then, sooner or later, but always before running `git commit`, run `git add` as needed.  The `add` step updates your *proposed next commit* from whatever you are adding.  (Note that a totally-new file goes into the index too, in this same way, it's just that it does not have to kick out some existing de-duplicated copy.)

Hence we now know two things:

- The *working tree* holds the useful copies of your files.
- The *staging area*—or *index*—holds the *proposed next commit*, which you update after you update the working tree.

When you do run `git commit`, Git simply packages up *whatever is in the index at that time* and puts that into the new commit as the set of Git-ified, read-only, stored-forever, compressed and de-duplicated files.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>What we can do at this point is currently rather limited.  The most common approach to handling corruption is to throw away the database entirely and clone a new one from a good copy, which works fine since Git is distributed and every repository has thousands of copies "out there".  Of course, it stops working if there's no other copy.

<sup>2</sup>They take a bit of space to hold the file's name, an internal blob hash ID, and a bunch of cache data—that's where the name *cache* comes in again—which typically amounts to a bit under 100 bytes per file: hardly anything these days.

<sup>3</sup>If you use `git commit -a`, note that this is roughly equivalent to running:

```
git add -u
git commit
```

That is, all the `-a` option really does is insert an "update" style `git add` *before* committing.  Git still builds the new commit out of the (updated-by-add) index.  There are several technical complexities here though.  These have to do with atomicity and the operation of Git hooks.  Putting them all together means that if you do *use* pre-commit hooks, you must be very clever at *writing* these pre-commit hooks, and/or avoid using `git commit -a`.  This is not the place for the details, though.

---

#### Submodules lead to an explosion of Git repositories

Now that you know:

- what a repository is; and
- how the index and working tree work

we're just about ready to move on to Git's *submodules*.

The very shortest definition of a Git submodule is that it is *another Git repository*.  This definition is perhaps a little *too* short, though.  It leaves out a key item, so let's try again: A *submodule* is:

- a Git repository, where
- some other Git repository *refers to* this Git repository; and
- some other Git repository *exercises some control over* this Git repository.

We now know that there must be *at least* two Git repositories involved, and one repository is put into some sort of supervisory position over the other.

This is how we define the term *superproject:* a superproject is a Git repository that has a *submodule*.  The superproject is the overseer / supervisor.

One superproject can be the superproject of multiple submodules.  (This is the case for you: you have at least three submodules.  So you have at least four Git repositories involved.)

A Git repository that is acting as a supervisor—playing the superproject role—can itself be a submodule for another Git repository.  In this case, the "middle" repository is both submodule *and* superproject.  I don't know if you have any of these: there's no evidence one way or another in your question.

Now, one thing about most Git repositories is this: they're *clones* of some other Git repository.  We mostly work with a clone.  So let's suppose that you have, as your superproject, your clone **R1** of some repository **R0**.  If your clone **R1** is the superproject for three submodules, those three Git repositories are themselves probably clones of three *more* repositories.  So we're suddenly talking about *at least eight Git repositories here*, in your basic question!

With eight or more repositories, things can rapidly become quite confusing.  There's no longer *the* repository, *the* working tree, *the* index, and so on.  Instead, there are *eight* repositories, *four* clones on your computer, *four* working trees, *four* Git index things, and so on.

**We need to be able to talk about each repository, index, and working tree independently, even though they may be somewhat interdependent.**  This means we need *names* for each one.  To simplify things somewhat, I'm going to use the name **R** for your superproject `git clone`, **S0** for one of the repositories representing `app/Services/Payment`, and **S1** for another of these.

#### How this all works

You cloned your superproject repository **R** from somewhere (from some repository **R0**), but after that, we can stop thinking about it for a while, so we'll just think about **R** itself.  Your repository **R** has commits, and these commits contain files and so on.

You selected some commit *in* **R** to check out:

```
git checkout somebranch
```

The name `somebranch` resolves to a raw commit hash ID `H`, and this is the commit your Git fishes out of **R** to populate the index and working tree so that you can *use* **R**.

There are, as yet, *no additional repositories*.  There is, however, a file named `.gitmodules` that came out of commit `H` in **R**.  Moreover, commit `H` lists some *gitlinks*.  A gitlink is a special entry that will go *into* a commit, and it contains two things:

- a path name, in this case `app/Services/Payment`, and
- some commit hash ID `S` (in this case `72602bc5d9e7cef136043791242dfdcfd979370c`).

These gitlinks go into the *index* in **R**.  We'll just talk about this one particular gitlink.

If you now run `git submodule update --init` (note the lack of `--remote` here), your Git commands, operating on repository **R**, will notice this gitlink in the index.  (There's no corresponding *files*, just the gitlink.)

Your superproject Git commands, executing this `git submodule update`, will now notice that you haven't yet cloned any submodules, and—because of the `--init` option—will run a `git clone` command for you.  This `git clone` command needs a URL.  The URL comes out of the `.gitmodules` file.

The *repository* that Git clones at this point is repository **S0** (perhaps over on GitHub: on some server anyway).  The clone gets hidden away,<sup>4</sup> creating a new repository **S1**.  Your Git software now runs a `git checkout` operation *within **S1*** so as to copy a commit into a working tree and index.

The *index* for **S1** is hidden away in the repository for **S1**, but the *working tree* for **S1** is placed into `app/Services/Payment`: the place you want the *files* you'll see and work with, from the submodule.  So now the ordinary directory (or folder, if you prefer that term) `app/Services/Payment` is full of ordinary files.  These comprise the *working tree* for **S1**.

Your submodule **S1** is now ready to use.  We have three repositories we need to think about: **R**, **S0**, and **S1**.  We have two staging areas / index-es: one that goes with **R** and one that goes with **S1**.  We have two working trees to use, one that goes with **R** and one that goes with **S1**.  The working tree for **S1** is *inside* the working tree for **R**, but the **R** *repository* won't use it.  Only the **S1** repository will *use* it.

---

<sup>4</sup>In modern Git, the clone's `.git` directory is stuffed into **R** in `.git/modules/`.  In ancient versions of Git, submodule clones go into a `.git` right in the submodule path—in this case `app/Services/Payment/.git`.

---

#### `git submodule update --remote`

The `--remote` flag to `git submodule update` tells it that instead of *obeying the superproject gitlink*—remember, this is an entry in the **R** index, under the name `app/Services/Payment`, that currently holds hash ID `72602bc5d9e7cef136043791242dfdcfd979370c`—your Git software should enter submodule **S1** and run:

```
git fetch origin
```

This reaches out to repository **S0**.  Repository **S0** has *its own* branch and tag names, and *its own* commits.  Repository **S1** was *cloned from* **S0** earlier, but **S0** might be updated any time.  So the `git fetch` step reaches out to the Git software that handles **S0** and gets, from that Git, any new commits for **S0** and puts them in your clone **S1**.  Then, as the final step, `git fetch origin` within **S1** creates or updates all of the *remote-tracking names* in **S1** that go with the *branch* names from **S0**.

This updates your (local) `origin/master`, `origin/develop`, `origin/feature/tall`, and so on in your **S1** based on the *branch names* as seen in **S0**.  You now have, in **S1**, all the *commits** from **S0**, and you know which commit *they* (**S0**) call the "latest" commit on their `master` for instance.

What your `git submodule update --remote` does now is *turn your name `origin/master` into a hash ID*.  The hash ID your **S1** Git gets from this operation is not `72602bc5d9e7cef136043791242dfdcfd979370c`.  It's actually `a7263787e5515abe18e7cfe76af0f26d9f62ceb4`.

Your *superproject* Git now directs your **S1** Git to run:

```
git checkout --detach a7263787e5515abe18e7cfe76af0f26d9f62ceb4
```

(or the same with `git switch`; in any case it's all being done internally in the latest versions of Git, though older ones literally run `git checkout` here).

This populates your **S1** index and working tree from commit `a7263787e5515abe18e7cfe76af0f26d9f62ceb4`.  So that's now the *current commit* in your **S1**.

Meanwhile, your *superproject* repository **R** still calls for commit `72602bc5d9e7cef136043791242dfdcfd979370c`.  That's what is in the index / staging-area for new commits you will make in **R**.

#### What to do about all this

If you *want* **R** to start calling for `a7263787e5515abe18e7cfe76af0f26d9f62ceb4`, you will simply need to run:

```
git add app/Services/Payment
```

while working in **R**.  This directs the **R** Git to run `git rev-parse HEAD` inside the **S1** Git, which finds the current checked-out commit's hash ID.  This hash ID then goes into the **R** index / staging-area, so that the *next* commit you make *in* **R** will call for that commit by that hash ID.

If you want **S** to have commit `72602bc5d9e7cef136043791242dfdcfd979370c` checked out instead, you have a number of options:

```
(cd app/Services/Payment && git checkout --detach 72602bc5d9e7cef136043791242dfdcfd979370c)
```

will do it, for instance.  Or you can run `git submodule update`.  This command, run in **R**, tells the **R** Git to read the commit hash IDs from the **R** index and run `git checkout` commands within each submodule, to force the submodule checkout back to the desired commit.

When you run `git submodule update --init`, if you add `--remote`, you're directing your **R** Git to fetch in each submodule and find the *latest* commit from some branch in the source repository (**S0** in our examples here).  The chosen branch is defined in various places in **R**, although it tends to be `master` or `main` these days.  The same goes for `git submodule update` without `--init`.  The `--init` merely means *do the initial clone if needed*.  The `--remote` part means *do the fetch and get the hash ID from a remote-tracking name*.  The crucial part is always the *hash ID*.  That comes from:

- your index, or
- some remote-tracking name

and that controls *which commit* your Git instructs the submodule Git to check out.

The `git status` and `git diff` commands, run *in* **R**, merely report whether the index (**R**'s index) and working tree (**S1**'s working tree checkout in this case) *match*.  If not, `git diff` tells you *what the difference is*, and `git status` just says "they are different".

Comment: " A gitlink is a special entry in a commit": nope: it is a special entry in the index (as you mention right after). We went over that already (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59633536/git-submodules-without-gitmodules-file/59634716?noredirect=1#comment105444518_59634716) (and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68767609/github-repository-folder-saved-as-shortcut-problem?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment121548074_68767609)

Comment: @torek Thank you  for your answer it was really informative but I'm wondering if I did add and commit the new commit would the superproject now be referring to the new submodules commit?

Comment: Yes, it would: that's the point of switching to some different submodule commit and then using `git add` in the superproject: to record (as an updated gitlink) the commit you'd like to refer-to from the new commit in the superproject.

Answer (score 0):

A [`git submodule update`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule/#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-update--init--remote-N--no-fetch--no-recommend-shallow-f--force--checkout--rebase--merge--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--recursive--jobsltngt--no-single-branch--ltpathgt82308203) should not "generate" any file, beside the submodule folder content.

A `git diff` i, the parent repository might show you what you mention, as seen in "[Starting with Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules#_starting_submodules)"

> If you run `git diff` on that, you see something interesting:
>
> ```sh
> $ git diff --cached DbConnector
> diff --git a/DbConnector b/DbConnector
> new file mode 160000
> index 0000000..c3f01dc
> --- /dev/null
> +++ b/DbConnector
> @@ -0,0 +1 @@
> +Subproject commit c3f01dc8862123d317dd46284b05b6892c7b29bc
> ```
>
> Although `DbConnector` is a subdirectory in your working directory, Git sees it as a submodule and doesn’t track its contents when you’re not in that directory.
> Instead, Git sees it as a particular commit from that repository.

Comment: when I command git status it prints the following   ```modified:   app/Services/Notification (new commits)
        modified:   app/Services/Payment (new commits)
        modified:   database/migrations (new commits)```

Comment: keep in mind That I didn't change any files!

Comment: @OmarAbdelaziz Are those folders the ones you see in the `.gitmodules` file?

Comment: I guess @torek explained it correctly thank you