# Git thinks stuff in my submodule is part of the main repo

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-for-windows

Somewhere in the course of committing and pushing code individually in my submodules, the root repo suddenly thinks that code in my submodule is actually part of the root repo; that is, files that are part of the submodule are now appearing as unstaged files to be added in the root repo. I verified this by running `git status`.

It's almost as if git forgot there are such things as submodules and thinks I added all these files. I did notice that the submodule has a `.git` *file* not a `.git` *directory*. In the file has this line

> gitdir: ../.git/modules/root-repo

and the root repo has a `.git/modules/sub-repo` folder as expected.

How do I get back to the correct state?

I suppose I can clone the root repo again and recursively update the submodules, but that seems heavy handed.

Answer (score 0):

> I suppose I can clone the root repo again and recursively update the submodules

That would be a good first state, in order to check:

- you still have a `.gitmodules` file which lists those submodules paths
- the root folders of those submodules are still considered gitlinks, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4185579/6309):

  ```
  cd /parent/folder/of/submodule
  git ls-files | grep 160000
  ```